# launcher-loader : java.lang.outofmemoryexception

Tags: android, memory, launcher

Whenever I tried to install my android application on device through eclipse, I get this error,then my app get installed but as soon as I returns out of my app,some other apps which I didnot open comes one after the other as I press the back button like contact app,native messaging app etc.. The launcher error details that I get are:

`01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632): FATAL EXCEPTION: launcher-loader
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:543)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:518)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:370)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:707)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at com.android.launcher2.IconCache.getFullResIcon(IconCache.java:82)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at com.android.launcher2.IconCache.getFullResIcon(IconCache.java:116)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at com.android.launcher2.IconCache.cacheLocked(IconCache.java:246)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at com.android.launcher2.IconCache.getTitleAndIcon(IconCache.java:161)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at com.android.launcher2.AllAppsList.updatePackage(AllAppsList.java:248)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at com.android.launcher2.LauncherModel$PackageUpdatedTask.run(LauncherModel.java:1637)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-01 10:21:15.820: E/AndroidRuntime(4632):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)`

is it device memory problem or what??

Comment: `com.android.launcher2.AllAppsList` is your app package name?

Comment: see this Please refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html and also run your project in real device and see if its still giving you that exception or not

Comment: as in application logs it's very clear you are using drawable of big sizes. so plz use small size drawables for launcher icons, Activity title bar icons etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try to wipe user data from your virtual device before launching your app. Sometimes a previous apk gets 'stuck' in my device and gives me errors until I clear the device memory. Since it's a runtime exception, i don't think it's caused by the amount of memory you have in your virtual device.